# Double Integral of exponentiation

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I find this example online, and I can't solve it at all.

[image]

All I know is that: [image]. Although I tried to transform the problem to my known rules, It's all in vain.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(z-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}} dz = \sqrt{\sigma^2 \pi}  $$

so

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5x^2+8xy-5y^2}$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5y^2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5x^2+8xy} dx \ dy$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5y^2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5(x^2-\frac{8}{5}xy)} dx \ dy$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5y^2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5(x^2-2\frac{8}{2*5}xy)} dx \ dy$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5y^2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5(x^2-2\frac{8}{2*5}xy+(.8y)^2 -(.8y)^2)} dx \ dy$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5y^2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5\left((x-.8y)^2 -(.8y)^2)\right)} dx \ dy$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5y^2+5*0.64y^2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5\left((x-.8y)^2 )\right)} dx \ dy$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-5y^2+5*0.64y^2}  \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}\pi} \ dy$$

Comment: $$\text{ When  I complete the integral, \math{pi}/3 comes out. Thanks a lot for your work.} $$

Comment: You are welcome!